# How to update existing sharepoint list using excel?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, excel

How will i update my existing list items with a new updated excel sheet?

Comment: Could you just copy paste it using edit? order the list first..

Comment: No,  there might be a lot of items , in that case manually would be a problem , i was searching for some REST api thing?

Comment: Hi @ViperOrton I have not tested this solution on SPO, and obviously certain steps will be different, unnecessary, or impossible, but the general premise should still hold:
**Answer**: [Import/Copy/Paste Data from Excel into Existing SharePoint List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/224375/44163).