# Copying column from excel into sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-server, list

When I look up how to copy a column from excel into a sharepoint list it says that a simple copy paste should work. When I do this however it ends up copying all of the values into one cell. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: How are you pasting into SharePoint list? Are you using "Quick Edit" view in the list when pasting?  See here https://sharepointmaven.com/3-ways-import-excel-sharepoint/ how to import excel data into SharePoint list

Answer (score 0):

Here're some references about how to copy column from excel into SharePoint list for you.

[How to Import Excel List Items to an Existing SharePoint List](https://blog.mydock365.com/import-excel-data-to-existing-sharepoint-list/)

[Here are 3 ways to import Excel data to SharePoint list](https://saketa.com/blog/import-excel-data-to-sharepoint-list/)

[Import/Copy/Paste Data from Excel into Existing SharePoint List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/224374/import-copy-paste-data-from-excel-into-existing-sharepoint-list)